# Fibonacci but with ratio of sum and difference of the the previous two terms

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I have discovered a pretty weird sequence
$$a_0=1$$
$$a_1= 2$$
$$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}}$$

The first few terms are:
$$1,\ 2,\ 3,\ 5,\,\ 4,\ -9,\ \frac{5}{13},\ -\frac{56}{61},\ \frac{423}{1033},...$$

The sequence is very unpredictable and looks very random. I wonder if there is a closed-form formula, perhaps analogous to Binet's formula, that calculates the $n$-th element of this sequence.

To simplify the problem, i tried splitting the sequence to its numerator and denominator
$$a_n = \frac{A_n}{B_n}$$
Combining with the recursive equation yields,
$$\frac{A_n}{B_n} = \frac{\frac{A_{n-1}}{B_{n-1}} +\frac{A_{n-2}}{B_{n-2}}}{\frac{A_{n-1}}{B_{n-1}} -\frac{A_{n-2}}{B_{n-2}} } = \frac{A_{n-1} B_{n-2}+A_{n-2}B_{n-1}}{A_{n-1} B_{n-2}-A_{n-2}B_{n-1}} $$

Then we set,
$$A_n = A_{n-1}B_{n-2} + A_{n-2}B_{n-1}$$
$$B_n = A_{n-1}B_{n-2} - A_{n-2}B_{n-1}$$
$$A_0 = B_0 = B_1 = 1$$
$$A_1 = 2$$

While i fell short of my goal of finding a closed-form formula, i think this is a great start. Can anyone find a closed-form formula?

Comment: I look at GCD of $A_n$ and $B_n$, and they seem to always be power of 2. I take the base-$2$ logarithm of the GCDs and got a sequence that match this [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A004695). Why?

Comment: Super interesting sequence! I plotted the first million points, and the sequence seems to stay very close to 0 (most are between -2 to 2), except for n = 70043, which reaches 308917.53101080377. An interesting note is that there are strips of higher density around 0. :)

Comment: @MaximeJaccon  won't precision be a problem here? Like this is chaotic system and even the slightest inaccuracies will likely be amplified given enough iterations

Comment: I got $a_7=-56/61$ with others as you have them. typo?

Comment: @coffeemath  oh yes it is a typo