# Fibonacci but with sum of reciprocals of the previous two terms

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Inspired by earlier post of mine, [Fibonacci but with ratio of sum and difference of previous two terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4884678/fibonacci-but-with-ratio-of-sum-and-difference-of-the-the-previous-two-terms)

$$a_0=a_1=1$$
$$a_n = \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} + \frac{1}{a_{n-2}}$$

Unlike my earlier variant which doesn't converge to constant and is very messy, this sequence converge to $\sqrt{2}$. Like the earlier question of mine, i seek a closed-form formula analogous to the Binet's formula for regular Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Previous effort, but no closed form: [How to prove this recursive sequence converges to $\sqrt 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1493494/89922)

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374566/limit-of-a-n2-frac1a-n-frac1a-n1)